# Probability that two different extractions from the same pool have common numbers

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a statistical problem that my really lacking knowledge can't solve, or even properly lay down.
Basically, I have a set of 100 balls, numbered 1 to 100.

I then proceed and extract 75 balls out of them, leaving 25 inside the urn.

I write down the numbers, and then I put all the balls back inside the urn.

Then I extract 5 more balls.

I would like to know what is the probability (but most importantly how to get to that value) that the latter 5 numbers are included in the earlier 75 ones, while both have been chosen from 100 possible values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first answer we can break up the numbers we can pull into two sets, the  "good" set of 75 numbers pulled in the first drawing (we'll call the set $\mathcal{G}$), and the "bad" set of numbers that were left in the pot in the first drawing (we'll call the set $\mathcal{B}$).  Now it doesn't matter what numbers were pulled.  We know that there are 75 numbers in $\mathcal{G}$ and 25 numbers in $\mathcal{B}$.  From here we will sample 5 balls/numbers without replacement, i.e. we will pull a ball out one at a time without putting them back in the urn until all 5 balls are drawn.  That means this is a sampling without replacement type problem.  There are multiple approaches to these types of problems.  I can discuss 3, we will let $P(E)$ be the probability of event E.

1) The box-and-fill method: Essentially here you will want to write down an empty box for each time you choose a ball.  We are choosing 5 balls, so we will have 5 boxes.
(Balls Drawn) = $[]_1[]_2[]_3[]_4[]_5$, and in each box we will write in the probability the event of interest occurs at that drawing, which is simply the fraction $p = \frac{\text{Number of Balls in} \mathcal{G}}{\text{Total Number of Balls}}$.  So in the first box we have 75 balls over 100 balls. $[]_1 = \frac{75}{100}$.    So now, we look at the second ball we will draw.  Note the numbers now change! We've removed 1 ball so we have 99 balls total, and only 74 in $\mathcal{G}$, so $[]_2 = \frac{74}{99}$.  You can repeat this in, updating after each drawing, and stopping at 5 to get your answer.  The probability is the product of the probability of each of these occuring:

$P(\text{All Balls Drawn are in } \mathcal{G}) = [\frac{75}{99}][\frac{74}{98}][\frac{73}{97}][\frac{72}{96}][\frac{71}{95}]$.

2) Utilizing $n$ choose $k$: We introduce the operator ${ n \choose k } = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$, where $!$ is the factorial operator.  This operator tells us the total number of possible combinations if we are to choose $k$ from an urn with $n$ total unique balls.  I offer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient as a link if you wish to read up on it.  See we can ask for the total number of combinations if we draw 5 balls from our pile of 100, 100 choose 5, ${ 100 \choose 5 } = \frac{100!}{95!5!}$.  Now we ask for the total number of combinations of drawing all 5 balls from the good pile.  Out of 75 balls we would choose to draw 5, ${ 75 \choose 5 } = \frac{75!}{70!5!}$.  Note the probability is the number of combinations of interest, divided by the total number of combinations:

$P(\text{All Balls Drawn are in } \mathcal{G}) = \frac{\text{All 5 in } \mathcal{G}}{\text{Total Number of Combinations}} = \frac{{ 75 \choose 5 }}{{ 100 \choose 5 }} = \frac{75!95!}{100!70!} = \frac{75 \cdot 74 \cdot 73 \cdot 72 \cdot 71}{100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98 \cdot 97 \cdot 96}$

The good news is our two answers agree!

3) Solve the oppposite: For a third answer, sometimes it is easier to ask the opposite question and subtract that probability from the total probability (1).  It is not necessarily the case here, but this trick is good to have in your back pocket, so I will ask a different question to highlight this.  For example, our question is equivalent to the question, what is the probability I draw $0$ balls from $\mathcal{B}$ if I draw 5.  Which is equal to P(All Balls Drawn are in $\mathcal{G}$) = 1 - P(Draw at least 1 ball in 5 from $\mathcal{B}$).

So if I were to ask you what the probability of drawing at least 1 ball in 5 from $\mathcal{B}$, it would be difficult using the two methods I show you.  You'd have to calculate the probability of drawing 1 ball from $\mathcal{B}$, the probability of drawing 2 balls from $\mathcal{B}$, the probability of drawing 3 balls from $\mathcal{B}$, the probability of drawing 4 balls from $\mathcal{B}$, the probability of drawing 5 balls from $\mathcal{B}$ and then add all these probabilities up.  Instead you could calculate the probability of drawing 0 balls from $\mathcal{B}$ and subtract this from the total probablity of any event occurring (1). Note,
$P(\text{Draw all 5 in } \mathcal{G}) = P(\text{Draw 0 in } \mathcal{B}) = \frac{75 \cdot 74 \cdot 73 \cdot 72 \cdot 71}{100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98 \cdot 97 \cdot 96}$, because the two are mutually exclusive (a ball is either in $\mathcal{B}$ or $\mathcal{G}$, not both!).  See then

$P(\text{Draw at least 1 in } \mathcal{B}) = 1 - P(\text{Draw 0 from} \mathcal{B}) = 1 - \frac{75 \cdot 74 \cdot 73 \cdot 72 \cdot 71}{100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98 \cdot 97 \cdot 96}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- If you want all $5$ of the second sample to be in the $75$ from the first sample, then one approach is to consider how many equally-probable ways you can select $5$ from $75$ and compare this with how many equally-probable ways you can select $5$ from $100$
- Alternatively you can calculate the probability the first of the $5$ was in the $75$ which is $\frac{75}{100}$ then, conditioned on that having happened, the probability the second of the $5$ was in the other $74$, and so on

Both approaches should give the same answer